# Citing background layer from ArcGIS Online that is used in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

How do you cite a background map layer that is used in ArcMap that is retrieved from ArcGIS Online?  For example the background layer is suppose to be credited from the U.S. Geological Survey and in the description it was digitized from the U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper 1183.

Answer (score 2):

First, I am new here, so take this with a grain of salt. In practice I generally cite the original source on the map using the minimal amount of information necessary to find the source. This is easiest if the map is part of ppublication, in which you can include a full citation elsewhere and not take up valuable map space.

The USGS provides good general guidelines here: http://www.usgs.gov/datamanagement/describe/citation.php

For this data set, you can find the metadata, along with several citations here:
http://nationalatlas.gov/metadata/lsoverp020.faq.html

If I were to cite this on a map, I might go with: "Landslide incidence and susceptibility (Source: U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper 1183)"

The original citation is:
"Radbruch-Hall, D.H., Colton, R.B., Davies, W.E., Lucchitta, Ivo, Skipp, B.A., and Varnes, D.J., 1982, Landslide Overview Map of the Conterminous United States: U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper 1183, U.S. Geological Survey, Washington, DC."

As the link above helpfully notes:

"These data were originally published as: Godt, J.W., 1997, Digital Representation of Landslide Overview Map of the Conterminous United States: U.S. Geological Survey Open-File Report 97-289, scale 1:4,000,000. Available online at http://landslides.usgs.gov/learningeducation/nationalmap/index.php."

Answer (score 2):

Most ArcGIS Online basemap providers are happy with the credit that should be available in the lower right hand corner of your map.

[image]

Just click to expand it.

[image]

It will even print on pdfexport or plot.